# wxpython gui documentation

Tags: wxpython

Has anyone got any idea where I can get detailed documentation on the wx.grid module. The demo doesnt do much explaining how the module works and finding good documentation online is proving impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/05/wxpython-documentation/

http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/grid/wx.grid.html